# Defining operations for a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was hoping someone could help me with the following. Is it possible to define operations + and $\cdot$ on this set to make it a vector space:
\begin{equation*}
V=\{f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}:f(x)=\exp(ax^2 + bx+c)\ \textrm{for some constant $c$}\}
\end{equation*}

I defined $+$ by $f+g=f(x)g(x)$ and $\lambda f = \exp(\lambda)f(x)$. When I check the axioms for a vector space the addition seems to work, but the scalar multiplication has some problems when it comes to distributive properties.

Answer (score 0):

[I assume your notation cshould convey that $c$ is fixed and $a,b$ vary to produce different functions.]

The obvious way would be to identify $\exp(ax^2+bx+c) $ with $(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2$.
That is we should let
$$ (f\oplus f)(x)=e^{-c}f(x)g(x)$$
and 
$$ (\lambda\odot f)(x)=f(x)^\lambda e^{c-\lambda c}.$$